# How can I globally have .some available in all of my .scala files in my project?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

In my akka http project I want to be able to do:

```
val a = 1.some
```

i.e. be able to use `.some` anywhere in my project

How can I do this without having to import cats in all my files?

Comment: If you are using **sbt** there is a way to configure it to automatically add a some import lines to all files, one of such lines may be `import cats.syntax.all._`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez is using a package object another way?   I think I have seen that used but not sure...

Comment: No AFAIK, you can't abstract over imports.